# Primitive classes in Java

Tags: java, class, types, primitive

What is the use of classes like `int.class` or `double.class`

For example you can not do something like

```
    Object val=getValue();
    if(val instanceof int){

    }
```

or

```
int i = new int();
```

Yes I know it is not possible because int is not Object type. However, what is the need to have those primitive classes? I do not see any clear explanation of this in [Oracle documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be useful for reflection.

For example if you wanted to use `Class.getDeclaredMethod` to lookup a method that took an `int` as a parameter, you might do something like:

```
//Find the method foo(int)
Method theMethod = theClass.getDeclaredMethod("foo", int.class);
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Looks like it is only for introspection. I would accept if someone does not provide any other usage.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `X.class` is the syntax for **class literals**. When `X` is the name of a class or an interface, the expression `X.class` **evaluates to the Class object representing that class or interface type** (which are reference types).

Since there are also Class objects for primitive types (used in reflection as noted by [Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528246/nicholas-daley)), **for consistency, they extended the syntax** so that for a primitive type `X`, the expression `X.class` also evaluates to the Class object representing that primitive type.

**#Note:** For all primitive types, this value is also available as the static field `TYPE` of the corresponding wrapper class. So `int.class` is equivalent to `Integer.TYPE`.